# Debugging multithreaded native code using ndk-debug

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I try to place a break point on a native component in Android, which is a function in a thread, the application terminates. I am using NDK r6b. Is debugging allowed in Android for multithreaded applications.

Answer (score 0):

yes now it is possible, refer this

[Screencast going from zero to debugging the Android NDK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMV7Xqcn39k)